# PERL: Multiline replacement on the command line without reading from a file

Tags: regex, perl, command-line, applescript

I have the following multiline input:

```
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/somefile1.txt
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/someotherfile.txt
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg
```

I want the following output (can also all be on a single line, I don't need the \n):

```
doc/myfiles/somefile1.txt
doc/myfiles/someotherfile.txt
doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg
```

Here is what I am trying to use without success:

```
| perl -le 'm@(doc.*)$@mg; print ${^MATCH}; '
```

The reason I am trying to do this without a file is because it is actually part of an apple script:

```
set myOtherVar to the clipboard
set thecommandstring to "echo \"" & myOtherVar & "\" | perl -le 'm@(doc.*)$@mg; print  ${^MATCH}; '" as string
set sedResult to do shell script thecommandstring
set the clipboard to sedResult
```

It takes the clipboard and sends it to the perl command. Then puts the result back in the clipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test your script, same issue here, the **perl** command in the answers return the last line only, but these commands works without using `the clipboard` command.

First solution : Use **the clipboard as «class utf8»**

```
set myText to the clipboard as «class utf8»
do shell script "perl -pe 's:^.*/doc/:doc/:' <<< " & (quoted form of myText) & " | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 pbcopy" --> copy STDOUT to the clipboard
```

Second solution: Use the **pbpaste** command.

```
do shell script "pbpaste -Prefer txt | perl -pe 's:^.*/doc/:doc/:' | LC_CTYPE=UTF-8 pbcopy" -- paste the clipboard, substitute text and copy STDOUT to the clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this perl command,

```
$ perl -pe 's/^.*doc/doc/g' file
doc/myfiles/somefile1.txt
doc/myfiles/someotherfile.txt
doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg
```

OR

```
$ perl -pe 's/^(?:(?!doc).)*//g' file
doc/myfiles/somefile1.txt
doc/myfiles/someotherfile.txt
doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg
```

Comment: First one gives me only: `doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg`.  Second one gives me:  `doc/myfiles/somefile1.txt
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/someotherfile.txt
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg`

Comment: try `perl -ple 's/^(?:(?!doc).)*//g' file`

Comment: Getting:  `doc/myfiles/somefile1.txt  
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/someotherfile.txt  
/Users/myuser/doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
| perl -pe "s/.*?\/doc\//\/doc\//g"
```

Comment: This one results in: /doc//doc//doc/myfiles/otherfoler/otherthing.jpg

Comment: really!! but i don't think so, i am damn sure you are doing something wrong, anyways i am on my windows machine, but later, sure i will come to this point

Comment: It should work but for some odd reason it doesn't. Anything after the new line doesn't appear to work. Here is the exact apple script I used: set myOtherVar to the clipboard
set thecommandstring to "echo \"" & myOtherVar & "\" | perl -pe 's@.*?/doc/@/doc/@g'" as string
set sedResult to do shell script thecommandstring
set the clipboard to sedResult

Comment: If the reason behind, is the new line then just change a bit, use `| perl -pe "s@.*?/doc/@/doc/@sg"`, just added s after the last forward slash. Let me know if still it's not working.